# Why were the earliest humans hunter gatherers instead of fruit eaters living on trees?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution

How is it that the earliest humans who evolved from primates (who live on trees and mostly eat fruit) became hunter-gatherers (which seems like a harder, more stressful and more dangerous way to find food)?

Comment: Perhaps because living in trees and eating fruit rather limits you to living in places where there are fruit-bearing trees.  Becoming a hunter-gatherer allows a species to greatly expand its range.